# Objective C regex inconsistency

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

So I have a working regex here: http://regex101.com/r/lU3sQ5

Basically, from this: `"/sample/path/directory" "/sample/path/directory/tmp\" tmp" 172.28.128.5 -alldirs -mapall=501:20`

I want to match:

`/sample/path/directory`

`/sample/path/directory/tmp\" tmp`

The problem is, when I use the exact same regex in objective c, it doesn't seem to work.. here's my code:

```
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"(.*?[^\\\"])\"" options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *pathArr = [regex matchesInString:line options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [line length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *pathResult in pathArr) {
        if (pathResult.range.length > 1) {
            NSString *path = [line substringWithRange:[pathResult rangeAtIndex:1]];
            NSLog(@"%@", path);
        }
    }
```

and here is the output I get:

```
/sample/path/directory
/sample/path/directory/tmp\
```

Any advice would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a safer regex for matching the inside of quotes that can contain escaped quotes:

```
(?<!\\)"(?:\\"|[^"\r\n])*"
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jD3xX1). Will add explanation in a moment. :)

In Objective C, to iterate over the matches, you could do:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<!\\\\)\"(?:\\\\\"|[^\"\r\n])*\"" options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])];
NSUInteger matchCount = [matches count];
if (matchCount) {
    for (NSUInteger matchIdx = 0; matchIdx < matchCount; matchIdx++) {
       NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:matchIdx];
       NSRange matchRange = [match range];
       NSString *result = [subject substringWithRange:matchRange];
     }
} 
else { // Nah, no matches. 
     }
```

**Explanation**

- The negative lookbehind `(?<!\\)` ensures that what precedes is not a backslash
- `"` match the opening quote
- `(?:\\"|[^"\r\n])` match a backslash + a quote, `|` OR one character that is neither a quote or a newline character
- The `*` quantifier repeats that zero or more times
- `"` matches the closing quote

Comment: FYI removed possessive quantifier (overkill) and added explanation :)

Comment: Nevermind, realized I needed 5 slashes `@"\"(.*?[^\\\\\"])\""`